# How can I use ajaxSuccess() outside of .ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

Im using Woocommece in a WordPress website and some of the plugins installed make requests to an API to check and validate a vat field.

Id like to use .ajaxSuccess() to tap into the ajax response thats returned so I can check to see if part of it contains some data and do something on screen.

So far Ive got this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   var event = 'updated_checkout'

   jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event){

       console.log('success');

   })

})
```

So the console spits out success. Great. But Im stuck as how I would move forward with this. I dont know how to get the XHR option or get he response in a variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the response from the request in the `$.ajaxSuccess()` handler, retrieve the `responseText` property from the jqXHR object passed to the handler function in the second argument:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var event = 'updated_checkout'

  $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ah, I thought I had to define them in some way before hand. Thanks